# what is causing write activities

Tags: postgresql, rds

I run a RDS postgresql instance.  Once in a while the instance experience a spike in write activity to the hard drive and query performance seem to suffer.  The spike lasts 5 - 10 min and goes away on its own.

The database supports a myriad of work loads including web query and batch data loads.  I want to correlate the spike in write activity to a particular type of work load, e.g. an increase in web traffic, or a larger than usual data set being loaded, but so far have not been successful.

I wonder if postgresql server has any instrumentation I could use for this purpose?  For example, is there a way to associate disk writes to particular queries / transactions?  If so I might be able to aggregate such information to see which type of transactions caused most of disk writes.

I know this is pretty vague.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your environment - for example I have to use mainly terminal command line stuff so I would have to log time snapshots of top I/O processes using `sudo iotop -b -n 1|head -15` or top 'postgres' processes `sudo iotop -b -n 1 -u postgres` - here I would find TID of top I/O processes.

Using `psql -U ... -d ... -t -c "select pid, query from pg_stat_activity where state='active' "` I can match TID to pid in postgresql process list.

But these spikes can be caused also by "stats collector" or autovacuum processes and this you can see only on OS level.